# Rails eager loading all records but still generating N+1 queries

Tags: ruby-on-rails, eager-loading

I'm using Rails 4.1 and have a very basic problem getting eager loading to work.

I've simplified a complex program into a very basic example of events, users and reservations:

The `event` model:

```
class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :reservations

  def reserved?(user)
    reservations.where(user: user).present?
  end
end
```

The `user` model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :reservations
end
```

The `reservation` model:

```
class Reservation < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :event
end
```

My `event controller`:

```
def index
  @events = Event.includes(:reservations).all
  @user = User.find(1)
end
```

My `views/events/index.html.erb` view:

```
<% @events.each do |event| %>
  <p>Event: <%= event.name %><br>
  Reserved?: <%= event.reserved?(@user) %><br></p>
<% end %>
```

I've created a user and three events. The resulting `server log` for the event index page:

```
Started GET "/events" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-12-03 11:26:20 +0800
Processing by EventsController#index as HTML
  User Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users"  WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
  Event Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "events".* FROM "events"
  Reservation Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "reservations".* FROM "reservations"  WHERE "reservations"."event_id" IN (1, 2, 3)
  Reservation Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "reservations".* FROM "reservations"  WHERE "reservations"."event_id" = ? AND "reservations"."user_id" = 1  [["event_id", 1]]
  Reservation Load (0.0ms)  SELECT "reservations".* FROM "reservations"  WHERE "reservations"."event_id" = ? AND "reservations"."user_id" = 1  [["event_id", 2]]
  Reservation Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "reservations".* FROM "reservations"  WHERE "reservations"."event_id" = ? AND "reservations"."user_id" = 1  [["event_id", 3]]
  Rendered events/index.html.erb within layouts/application (10.0ms)
Completed 200 OK in 76ms (Views: 68.7ms | ActiveRecord: 1.3ms)
```

As you can see, rails correctly eager loads all the reservations for my events. However it then proceeds to query the database again during the `reserved?(user)` call. What am I doing wrong? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `reserved?` method uses the `where` method of the `reservations` association.  The `where` method is an ARel method that is used to build SQL queries.  Calling `present?` on the result of the `where` method causes the query to be executed.

To avoid doing another database lookup in `reserved?`, you should use a Ruby collection method instead, for example:

```
def reserved?(user)
  reservations.select { |reservation| reservation.user == user }.empty?
end
```

Or, for a more concise version (someone added this as a comment, but it looks like it may have been deleted):

```
def reserved?(user)
  reservations.map(&:user_id).include?(user.id)
end
```

Comment: I agree with this solution but this might be a bad thing to eager load.  If you have 1000 reservations per event this solution is less than ideal.  Also do `reservations.any? { |reservation| reservation.user == user }` it is more optimized.

Comment: Many thanks. Is there a good alternative to using the collection method with `where` scopes without generating the SQL queries? e.g. a re-write of `reservations.late_cancelled.map(&:user_id).include?(user.id)` and `scope :late_cancelled, -> {joins(:event).where("reservations.cancelled_at > (events.starts_at - events.late_cancel_window * INTERVAL '1 SECOND')") }` I have a lot of scopes that I chain together and really enjoy this flexibility in Rails.

Comment: drhenner: Agreed on the perils of eager loading; in my specific application, events are restricted to around 20 or so reservations each.